# Rigorous justification for this conditional probability inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space. Consider a collection of bounded real random variables $X(\gamma)$, for $\gamma\in[0,1]$, defined on this probability space. Let $(\gamma_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of iid random variables taking values in $[0,1]$. The family $\{\gamma_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is assumed to be independent of the family $\{X(\gamma) : \gamma \in [0,1]\}$. Consider the following inequality for a given $\delta>0$:

$$\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}P\bigg(\Big|X(\gamma_i)-E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)]\Big|>\delta \bigg | \sigma(\gamma_i) \bigg)\leq \sup_{\gamma \in [0,1]}P\bigg(\Big|X(\gamma)-E[X(\gamma)]\Big|>\delta \bigg) .$$

It seems to me that this inequality is true, since once we condition on $\gamma_i$, the $i$th probability on the left must appear on the right as well.

But how to show it rigorously? Any help on this is very appreciated.

EDIT: In fact I would be happy if someone could just give a rigorous proof of the statement

$$E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)(\omega)=E[X(\gamma_i(\omega)) ,\quad \omega\in\Omega.$$

Comment: Are you assuming that the family $\{\gamma_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is independent of the family $\{X(\gamma) : \gamma \in [0,1]\}$?

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Yes. I will add it explicitly.

Comment: Ok, this is a fairly standard exercise in measure theoretic probability then, assuming you have measurability of the map $(\gamma,\omega)\to X(\gamma)(\omega)$. The point is that if $f(\gamma) = P(|X(\gamma) - E[X(\gamma)]|>\delta)$, then by independence $P(|X(\gamma_i) - E[X(\gamma_i)]|>\delta | \gamma_i) = f(\gamma_i)$ almost surely. See Theorem 1.26(x) here for example: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/courses/735/notes2014.pdf

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian In the notation of 1.26(x) what is $\phi$ in this case? And what are $X,Y$?

Comment: There's work to do here and it's too long for a comment. I'll try to write out an answer later unless someone else does it first.

Comment: Where does the question arose?

Comment: Sorry about that, it isn't a simple application of that result I linked. The basic issue is, as you note, that $X$ is playing the role of $\phi$ in that result, so it doesn't just apply. Unfortunately, the argument I was thinking about also doesn't seem to work because $X$ is not assumed to have any path regularity. I'll play with it again tomorrow if I get a chance.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I thought the same. This argument uses only the independence between $X$ and $Y$. In my case I believe we must use the independence of $\gamma_i$ from the entire family $\{X(\gamma) : \gamma \in [0,1]\}$.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian If you have an argument that works assuming continuous paths I would be very glad.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here are my few cents. I hope that others point out my mistakes, which I almost definitely made.

**Let's take the left side appart**:
For each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, the conditional expectation
$$E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)]:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$$
is a random variable in the sense that
$$E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)](\omega):=E[X(\gamma_i(\omega))],\quad \omega\in\Omega.$$
By construction of the conditional expactation, this function factorizes over $\gamma_i$, i.e. there exists a function $h:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ measurable, such that
$$E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)](\omega) = h\circ \gamma_i(\omega),\quad \omega\in\Omega.$$
For this, we need the measurability condition from above.

In the same way - "conitional probability is just conditional expectation of an indicator function" - the conditional probability
$$ P\bigg(\Big|X(\gamma_i)-E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)]\Big|>\delta \bigg | \sigma(\gamma_i) \bigg):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$$
is also "just" a measurable function in the sense that
$$P\bigg(\Big|X(\gamma_i)-E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)]\Big|>\delta \bigg | \sigma(\gamma_i) \bigg)(\omega)=P\bigg(\Big|X(\gamma_i(\omega))-E[X(\gamma_i(\omega))]\Big|>\delta \bigg)=g\circ \gamma_i(\omega)$$
for a measurable $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$.

**Bringing both sides together**:
On the left, we have
$$\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}g\circ \gamma_i:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}.$$
For each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\omega\in\Omega$, we indeed have
$$g( \gamma_i(\omega))\leq \sup_{\gamma\in[0,1]}g(\gamma)=\sup_{\gamma\in[0,1]} P\bigg(\Big|X(\gamma)-E[X(\gamma)]\Big|>\delta \bigg).$$

Taking the supremum on the left side yields the desired inequality.

**Notes**:

1. I still don't see, where the independence of $(X(\gamma))_{\gamma\in[0,1]}$ and $(\gamma_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is needed. Maybe @chris-janjigian could help and spot my error of reasoning.
2. @chris-janjigian provided a source above. As we both noted, one needs the measurability of $(\gamma,\omega)\mapsto X(\gamma)(\omega):=X(\gamma(\omega))(\omega)$.
3. I don't think that one needs the $(\gamma_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ to be iid.

Comment: 2,3) you're right (but in 2, the map is just $(\gamma,\omega) \to X(\gamma)(\omega)$, no $\gamma(\omega)$). To help you with 1), independence of $X$ and $\{\gamma_i\}$ is crucial here: $\mathbb E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)](\omega) = \mathbb E[X(\gamma_i(\omega))] := \int_{\Omega} X(\gamma_i(\omega))(\omega')d\mathbb P(\omega')$ and the same with conditional probability later. You can't just "fix" variable we're conditioning on and "integrate" the rest to get conditional expectation/probability. One thing that is sufficient for it, is independence, as in this example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you provide the details for why the relationship $E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)](\omega)=E[X(\gamma_i(\omega))],\omega\in\Omega,$ holds? I think this is where independence is needed.

Comment: @DominikKutek I would be very grateful if you could provide the details for how to  prove $E[X(\gamma_i)|\sigma(\gamma_i)](\omega)=E[X(\gamma_i(\omega))],\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: You can look here, I proved the general result for case of one dimensional random variables, but it's just the matter of changing some letters and the proof remains the same for arbitrary metric spaces.
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3330876/601852

Comment: @DominikKutek In the notation of your answer, what is $f$ here? I think we should have $X(\gamma)$, $\gamma_i$ taking the roles of $X,Y$ respectively, but I don't see which function $f$ to choose.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the original question, but here is an argument for the case where $X(\cdot)$ is a random variable taking values in $C[0,1]$. The same idea works if it is either right- or left- continuous. For simplicity, I will keep the boundedness hypothesis and without loss of generality, take $\|X\|_\infty \leq 1$. It's not needed, but will simplify things a bit.

Just to sketch out the main idea, if $X$ is continuous, you can pretend $\gamma_i$ is a random variable taking only finitely many possible values by approximating it by one. This is always possible by a truncation argument. Path continuity lets you undo the discretization by taking a limit. There may be an abstract way of doing this more generally, but I couldn't see the argument quickly. I probably need to spend some time refreshing myself on measure theory.

Anyway, the first claim is that if we define $g(\gamma) = E[X(\gamma)] = \int X(\gamma,\widetilde{\omega}) P(d\widetilde{\omega})$ then $E[X(\gamma_i)|\gamma_i](\omega) = g(\gamma_i(\omega))$ almost surely. Be careful about the notation here, it is not true that $g(\gamma_i) = E[X(\gamma_i)]$.  The former is a random variable and the second is a constant. Because of this notational issue, I am going to keep the integrals around, even though it looks ugly. The claim is that for all $h \in C_b[0,1]$,

$$
\int X(\gamma_i(\omega),\omega) h(\gamma_i(\omega)) P(d\omega) = \int \int X(\gamma_i(\omega),\widetilde{\omega})P(d\widetilde{\omega}) h(\gamma_i(\omega)) P(d\omega).
$$

Call $\eta_m(\omega) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{k}{m} 1_{[k/m,(k+1)/m)}(\gamma_i(\omega)) + 1_{\{1\}}(\gamma_i(\omega))$. Then we have $\lim_{m\to\infty} \eta_m(\omega) = \gamma_i(\omega)$ surely. Note also that $\eta_m$ takes on only finitely many values. By dominated convergence,

$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}E[X(\eta_m)h(\eta_m)] = \lim_{m\to\infty} \int X(\eta_m(\omega),\omega) h(\eta_m(\omega)) P(d\omega) \\=\int X(\gamma_i(\omega),\omega) h(\gamma_i(\omega)) P(d\omega) = E[X(\gamma_i)h(\gamma_i)].
$$
We used path regularity and smoothness of our test function in this step to obtain the almost sure convergence of the integrand. As a comment here, by playing around with the form of the truncation, it would suffice to assume that $X$ is either right- or left- continuous.

On the other hand,
$$E[X(\eta_m)h(\eta_m)] = \sum_{k=0}^m E\left[X(\eta_m)h(\eta_m) 1_{\{\eta_m = k/m\}}\right] \\= \sum_{k=0}^m E\left[X(k/m)h(k/m) 1_{\{\eta_m = k/m\}}\right] \\= \sum_{k=0}^m E[X(k/m)]h(k/m)P(\eta_m=k/m) \\= \int \int X(\eta_m(\omega),\widetilde{\omega}) P(d\widetilde{\omega})h(\eta_m(\omega)) P(d\omega)$$

In the third equality, we used independence of the process $X$ and $\sigma(\gamma_i)$. The fourth equality is the definition. Sending $m \to \infty$ and again using dominated convergence, we have

$$
\int X(\gamma_i(\omega),\omega) h(\gamma_i(\omega)) P(d\omega) = \int \int X(\gamma_i(\omega),\widetilde{\omega})P(d\widetilde{\omega}) h(\gamma_i(\omega)) P(d\omega).
$$
This gives the claim.

To answer your question (with the extra hypothesis anyway), it suffices to show that if we define
$$q(\gamma,\delta) = P(|X(\gamma) - E[X(\gamma)]|>\delta) = \int 1_{\{|X(\gamma,\widetilde{\omega}) - g(\gamma)|>\delta\}}P(d\widetilde{\omega})$$

then $P(|X(\gamma_i) - E[X(\gamma_i)|\gamma_i] > \delta|\gamma_i) = q(\gamma_i(\omega),\delta)$ almost surely. We have shown that we can replace $E[X(\gamma_i)|\gamma_i]$ in this expression with $g(\gamma_i)$.

Let $f \in C_b([-1,1] \times [0,1])$ be given. The same argument as above shows that for $h \in C_b(0,1)$,

$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}E[f(X(\eta_m),\eta_m)h(\eta_m)] = E[f(X(\gamma_i),\gamma_i)h(\gamma_i)]
$$
and
$$
E[f(X(\eta_m),\eta_m)h(\eta_m)] = \int\int f(X(\eta_m(\omega),\widetilde{\omega}),\eta_m(\omega))P(d\widetilde{\omega}) h(\eta_m(\omega)) P(d\omega)
$$
Sending $m \to \infty$ lets us replace $\eta_m$ by $\gamma_i$ in this expression. By density, this holds for all bounded Borel functions in place of $f$ and $h$ and in particular in the case where $f(x,y) = 1_{\{|x-g(y)|>\delta\}}$. We then have for any $h \in B_b[0,1]$
$$
E[f(X(\gamma_i),\gamma_i)h(\gamma_i)] =  \int\int f(X(\gamma_i(\omega),\widetilde{\omega}),\gamma_i(\omega))P(d\widetilde{\omega}) h(\gamma_i(\omega)) P(d\omega) \\=  \int q(\gamma_i(\omega),\delta) h(\gamma_i(\omega)) P(d\omega),
$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: Just as a quick comment here, the key step in the argument is being able to condition on $\eta_m = k/m$. I think it should be possible to replace that part of the argument with an argument involving the regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\gamma_i$ without needing path regularity. I'll think about that another day if I remember.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Some questions I have : 1) The measurability of $\gamma\to g(\gamma) = E[X(\gamma)] $ comes from Fubini's Theorem? 2) In $\int \int X(\eta_m(\omega),\widetilde{\omega}) P(d\widetilde{\omega})h(\eta_m(\omega)) P(d\omega)$ we are actually using the DCT twice right?

Comment: (continued) 3) You showed that $E[X(\gamma_i)h(\gamma_i)]=E[(E[X(\gamma)]\circ \gamma_i) h(\gamma_i)] $ for all $h\in C[0,1]$. To show that it holds for a Borel function $h$ on $[0,1]$ I need to find a sequence $(h_n)\subset C[0,1]$ converging pointwise a.e. to $h$ and use the DCT again right?

Comment: 4) Is it true that we can approximate a borel function on $[-1,1] \times [0,1]$ as a limt a.e. of a sequence of functions in $C([-1,1] \times [0,1] )$ ?

Comment: Yes, measurability can be obtained from Fubini's theorem. Yes, you use can DCT twice. You could find such a sequence of functions, but it is not necessary to do so. It suffices to consider continuous functions because they are a separating family (if two measures agree on continuous test functions, they are the same measure). Yes, you can approximate Borel functions as a.e. limits of continuous functions on [-1,1] $\times$ [0,1]. A fancy proof of this would be to observe that probability measures on $[-1,1]\times [0,1]$ are inner and outer regular, then use Urysohn's lemma for the functions.

Comment: Ok but you are showing the equality of which two measures here? Don't we just want to identity the conditional expectation?

Comment: It depends how you think about the problem. Finite/positive Borel measures on reasonable topological spaces can be thought of as functionals on continuous functions. This is the Riesz representation theorem. In this example, the LHS and RHS both define measures $h \mapsto E[f(X(\gamma_i),\gamma_i)h(\gamma_i)]$ and $h \mapsto$ the RHS of the last equality. Because those measures agree on continuous functions, they agree on Borel functions.

Comment: Ok I think I prefer to think with an approximating sequence of continuous functions :) Also you said that the boundedness assumption was not necessary. But don't we need it for the DCT?

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124440/discussion-between-chris-janjigian-and-alphie).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in my opinion, the crux of the problem is to make sense of all the symbols written up there.

I'm almost there but I came up with two questions I could not yet answer:
Fix $i\in\mathbb{N}$. What is the object $X(\gamma_i)$? I thought it to be the function
$$X(\gamma_i):\Omega \to \mathbb{R},\quad X(\gamma_i)(\omega):=X(\gamma_i(\omega))(\omega).$$
If so, why is this even a random variable, i.e. why is it measurable? Do we have other assumptions on the concrete distributions of the $\gamma_i$, for example they take values in a discrete subset of $[0,1]$?

I'm sorry, I don't have the reputation to make a comment yet, so I had to write an "answer".

Comment: Thank you for your question. You are right about the definition  of $X(\gamma_i)$. I believe its measurability follows from the joint measurability of $X(\gamma)(\omega)$ with respect to $(\gamma,\omega)$, which we can assume. The distributions of the $\gamma_i$'s on $[0,1]$ are arbitrary.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I think I can now construct a counter-example to the measurability of $X(\gamma)$ for a family of m'ble RVs $(X(t))_{t\in [0,1]}$ and a RV $\gamma$. I will link the post, when I've written up the proof.
I will think about your problem tomorrow, sadly I don't have the time to finish it today.